# how to alert Error Messagen in Marketing form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-marketing

i have a Marketing form and i need to change the display error message see Picture.
my form : [image]

and I want That my error message be like This: [image]

---

```html
   here is my Code :

        <div>
                <div>
                    <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="layout-editable" value="marketing-designer-layout-editable">
                        <meta type="xrm/designer/setting" name="layout-max-width" value="600px" datatype="text" label="Layout max width">
                            <form data-container="true" style="null" action = "" method = "get" novalidate>
                                    <style>
                                        div[data-editorblocktype=Field-radioButtons] 
                                        {
                                            width: 25% ;
                                            text-align: left ;
                                        }

                                        div[data-editorblocktype=Field-radioButtons] input 
                                        {
                                            width: auto;
                                            height: auto;
                                            margin-bottom: 3px;
                                            float: right;
                                        }

                                        div[data-editorblocktype=Field-radioButtons] span.lp-radioButton 
                                        {
                                            /* This rule is needed to style all radio button fields. For product constraints each option is defined as input and label wrapped into a span*/
                                            display: block;
                                            margin: 2px;
                                        }

                                        [data-layout="true"]
                                        {
                                                margin: 0 auto;
                                                max-width: /* @layout-max-width */
                                                600px /* @layout-max-width */
                                                ;
                                        }
                                    </style>

                                        <div data-layout="true" tabindex="0">
                                                <div data-section="true" class="emptyContainer">
                                                    <div style=" display: flex;width: 100%;flex-wrap: wrap;">
                                                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                                        <div data-container="true" class="columnContainer" data-container-width="100" style="display: block; min-height: 70px; min-width: 20px; width: calc(100% - 0px); padding: 10px; float: left; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; flex-direction: column;">
                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="Image">
                                                                <div class="imageWrapper" width="100%" align="Center">  
                                                                    <img alt="Test Newsletter" class="" src="https://test/Y0gdmVq8p6izVL5Ig6QF2elBYT71iDv3rsgqHc-uOI8!" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; position: static; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;">
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="Text"><p><big><big><span><strong>Abonnieren Sie unseren </strong></span></big></big><br>
                                                                <span><big><big><strong>Test Newsletter!</strong></big></big></span></p>
                                                                <p><span style="font-size:16px;">Nach der Übermittlung Ihrer Kontaktdaten erhalten Sie von <em>info@test.de</em> einen Bestätigungslink, um die Anmeldung abzuschließen.</span></p>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="Text"><p>* Pflichtfelder</p> </div>

                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="Field-text" style="text-align: center;">
                                                                <div class="marketing-field" style="text-align: center;">
                                                                    <div class="lp-form-field" data-required-field="false" style="text-align: left;"><label class="lp-ellipsis" for="3f746946-34b4-442c-a677-e232cdd2bc40" title="">Vorname</label>
                                                                        <input class="lp-form-fieldInput form-control form-text lp-form-fieldInput" data-requirederrormessage="Pflichtfeld! Bei Bedarf  ein Pseudonym verwenden" id="3f746946-34b4-442c-a677-e232cdd2bc40" name="3f746946-34b4-442c-a677-e232cdd2bc40" placeholder="Vorname" style="width:100%" title="" type="text" value="Vorname" autocomplete="given-name">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="Field-text">
                                                                <div class="marketing-field">
                                                                    <div class="lp-form-field" data-required-field="false"><label class="lp-ellipsis" for="e1dfc514-f301-4cb2-855a-4c8fa8331207" title="">Nachname</label>
                                                                        <input class="lp-form-fieldInput form-control form-text lp-form-fieldInput" data-requirederrormessage="Pflichtfeld! Bei Bedarf ein Pseudonym verwenden." id="e1dfc514-f301-4cb2-855a-4c8fa8331207" name="e1dfc514-f301-4cb2-855a-4c8fa8331207" placeholder="Nachname" style="width:100%" title="" type="text" value="Nachname " autocomplete="family-name">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="Field-email">
                                                                <div class="marketing-field">
                                                                    <div class="lp-form-field" data-required-field="true"><label class="lp-ellipsis" for="7f685ebb-7c54-4cff-a1bc-772562d25c38" title="">E-Mail-Adresse</label><span class="lp-required">*</span>
                                                                        <input class="lp-form-fieldInput form-control form-text lp-form-fieldInput" id="7f685ebb-7c54-4cff-a1bc-772562d25c38" name="7f685ebb-7c54-4cff-a1bc-772562d25c38" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" required="required" style="width:100%" title="" type="email" autocomplete="email">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                                        
                                                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            <div data-section="true" class="">
                                                <div style="
                                                    display: flex;
                                                    width: 100%;
                                                    ;flex-wrap: wrap;">
                                                    
                                                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                                        <div data-container="true" class="columnContainer" data-container-width="100" style="display: block; min-height: 70px; min-width: 20px; width: calc(100% - 0px); padding: 10px; float: left; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word; flex-direction: column;">
                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="Field-dropdown" style="display: none;">
                                                                <div class="marketing-field">
                                                                    <div class="lp-form-field" data-required-field="true"><label class="lp-ellipsis" for="f7796368-6e5b-e911-a96e-000d3ab496ce" title="">Datenquelle</label><span class="lp-required">*</span>
                                                                        
                                                                        <select class="lp-form-fieldInput" id="f7796368-6e5b-e911-a96e-000d3ab496ce" name="f7796368-6e5b-e911-a96e-000d3ab496ce" required="required" title="">
                                                                            <option value="120000002">E-Mail (nachverfolgen)</option>
                                                                            <option value="120000001">Aktion</option>
                                                                            <option selected="selected" value="120000003">Newsletter / Mailing</option>
                                                                            <option value="181510000">Projekt-Workshop</option>
                                                                            <option value="181510001">Registrierung auf Webportal</option>
                                                                            <option value="120000000">Veranstaltung</option>
                                                                            <option value="100000000">Visitenkarte erhalten </option>
                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div data-editorblocktype="SubscriptionListBlock">
                                                                <div class="marketing-subscription-list"><input class="lp-form-fieldInput" id="e6648b6d-0894-e911-a971-000d3ab496c3" name="e6648b6d-0894-e911-a971-000d3ab496c3" required="required" type="checkbox"> <label for="e6648b6d-0894-e911-a971-000d3ab496c3">Ich habe die <a href="https://www.test.de/datenschutz">Datenschutzerklärung</a> gelesen und akzeptiert.<span class="lp-required">*</span></label><br>
                                                                     
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="btn." data-editorblocktype="SubmitButtonBlock">
                                                                <p align="“center“"><button class=".btn .btn-primary lp-form-button lp-form-fieldInput" name="submit" type="submit">Anmeldung absenden</button></p>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                            </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far to achieve that? You can either do it with form validation or better yet using JS to check if the input field is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has already been mentioned in the comments, you should use JavaScript to validate the form. Here is a runnable code snippet:

```js
function formValidate() {
  var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var tc = document.getElementById("tc");
  if (fname.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById("errfname").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("errorbox").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errfname").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (lname.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById("errlname").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("errorbox").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errlname").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (email.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById("erremail").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("errorbox").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("erremail").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (tc.checked === false) {
    document.getElementById("errtandc").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("errorbox").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("errtandc").style.display = "none";
  }
  if (fname.length !== 0 && lname.length !== 0 && email.length !== 0 && tc.checked === true) {
    window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email] {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
}

.errorbox {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 98%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Example form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="errorbox" id="errorbox">
    <p id="errfname" style="display: none;">Please enter your first name!</p>
    <p id="errlname" style="display: none;">Please enter your last name!</p>
    <p id="erremail" style="display: none;">Please enter your Email address!</p>
    <p id="errtandc" style="display: none;">Please check the terms and conditions check box!</p>
  </div>
  <h1>Test newsletter!</h1>
  <p>This is a test newsletter</p>
  <p><span style="color: red;">* </span> Required fields</p><br>
  <span style="color: red;">*</span>First name:
  <input type="text" placeholder="First name" id="fname"><br><br>
  <span style="color: red;">*</span>Last name:
  <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="lname"><br><br>
  <span style="color: red;">*</span>Email-address:
  <input type="email" placeholder="Email address" id="email"><br><br><br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="tc">I agree to the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a> of this website.<br>
  <button onclick="formValidate()">Submit</button>

</body>

</html>
```